# Access data files in production play server

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a Play in Scala application whose directory structure looks like this:

- app
- conf
- data      <- Added manutally
- logs
- project
- public
- target
- test

The data directory I have manually added, it contains a number of JSON files that the application depends on. Getting hold of them in the code seems easy enough, and works well when I run "play run". This is the code I use to reference them:

```
val projectRoot = Play.application.path.getAbsolutePath
val statFiles = new File(projectRoot + "/data/"+tier+"/usage").listFiles
```

However, when I run "play start" I get NullPointerExceptions, the stack trace looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.length(ArrayOps.scala:192) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.size(SeqLike.scala:106) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.size(ArrayOps.scala:186) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.Builder$class.sizeHint(Builder.scala:69) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

My guess is that somehow in the way the production application is setup, the ability to reference the files in the same way gets lost. That's not completely obvious from the stack trace, though... I was wondering if this is likely to be caused by the fact that I've added this data directory and not built it properly, and if so how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

*Data* folder is not copied by default to your target folder.

Few ways you can solve this are:

1. Move *data* to *conf* folder and access it using new File("conf/data" + tier +"/usage")
2. Sbt can add unmanaged resource directory to your production build with

> unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value /
>   "data"

You can read more aout this on http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html